# Text-align not working for a piece of text

Tags: css, html, wordpress

please take a look at [this page](http://glamourina.pl).

As you can see there are some "read more" buttons. (translated - "czytaj więcej").
This are just after the excerpts. I want to center this read more button.

I gave the `a href` ...  the following class:

```
class="readmorebtn"
```

And this CSS:

```
.readmorebtn{font-size:23px; text-align:center !important;}
```

But for some reasons it's not working. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `a` element for your button, so `a` element is `inline` by default, so even if you `center`, the text has no place to get centered,as `inline` elements don't take `100%` horizontal space, so inorder to center the text, you need to make it `inline-block` or `block`

```
.readmorebtn {
    display: block;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-align: center; /* No need of !important here */
}
```

---

If you are using `inline-block` the element will be `inline` and also `block` but again, you need to define some `width` to your `inline-block` element. Whereas `block` level element will take up entire horizontal space.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PDJQu/) (See what if you don't make it a block level element)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/PDJQu/1/) (Making it a `block` level element)

Answer (score 1):

a element can't have the width because it's an inline element and without width you can't align to center so you should add `display: inline-block; or display: block;` to your a

```
.readmorebtn {
    display: block;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I thought that it is simple text, so the text-align should work. Thanks